# display a popup on click a pageAction when it is hidden (grayed out, inactive)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a simple chrome extension that would be enabled for a few web sites and that opens another page (in a new tab) when clicked. So far so good and pretty similar to [Google's tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted).

Following [Google's tips](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction), I am using a page action for this extension that "make sense for only a few pages" and I use `declarativeContent` to `ShowPageAction()` for those few sites (matching by host). This works. In the selected sites, the icon is enabled and when clicked, it opens the new tab. In the rest of the sites, the icon is grayed out and when clicked, it just shows the extension's name and the menu (options, remove extension, etc.).

But I also want to show a popup for those sites where the extension should be inactive (just a plain html explaining that the extension does not work in that page and why). The problem is that the onClicked event "[will not fire if the page action has a popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#event-onClicked)". So, for the main functionality of my extension to work (open a new page in a new tab when clicked) I had to remove the default popup in the manifest.json and I can't figure out how to include a popup for the sites where the extension is inactive.

Here's the code I am using now.

manifest.json

```
  {
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "permissions": ["storage", "declarativeContent", "tabs"],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "images/get_started128.png"
      }
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

background.js

```
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'developer.chrome.com'},
      })
      ],
          actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
    }]);
  });
});

// listen to onClicked event ...
// ... but "This event will not fire if the page action has a popup." 
// see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#event-onClicked
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab) {
  var newURL = "http://www.youtube.com/";
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

Comment: Simply declare browser_action in manifest.json instead of using page_action and declarativeContent. In your popup script you'll simply check the active tab's URL (see examples for chrome.tabs.query) and depending on that show/hide the corresponding DOM element in your popup html.

Comment: thx @wOxxOm I'm not in my laptop to test it, but while I get home, a couple of questions. 1. I think the `onClicked` event of browser_action will also not fire if there is a popup, just like in page_action. So, I'm not sure if this is the solution. 2. Using browser_action would I need to "manually" gray out the icon?, or it does it automatically also, just like page_action?.

Comment: 1. Uhm, don't use onClicked, you don't need it, simply put the code in your popup script. 2. Use a manually grayed icon by default in manifest.json and invoke chrome.browserAction.setIcon from background script (for example in chrome.tabs.onUpdated listener) with a colored icon on applicable URLs.

Comment: thx @wOxxOm I'll try that. For some reason I assumed `chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });` wouldn't work in the popup script and would only work in an `onClicked` event. But I guess you are right. I don't really see a reason why it wouldn't.